# Observable retornando undefined

Tags: angular

Estou tentando carregar uma lista em tela no meu navegador usando Observable, porém não estou tendo sucesso, esse é registro que existe  na minha url;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a classe de serviços

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Restaurant } from './restaurant.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class RestaurantService {
  public url: String = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  //  this.url = environment.url;
   }

   restaurants(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/restaurants`)
    .map(response => response.json())
  }
```

realizei um teste na classe de componente utilizando console.log como podem ver abaixo;

```
export class RestaurantsComponent implements OnInit {

  restaurants: Restaurant[]

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurants()
    .subscribe(restaurants => {
    console.log('o valor é ' , this.restaurants = this.restaurants);
    })
  }
```

E o resultado está sendo esse;

```
o valor é  undefined
```

O que será que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema e que voce esta usando o this duas vezes. **this.restaurants != restaurants**

```
.subscribe(restaurants => {
    this.restaurants =restaurants 
    console.log('o valor é ' , this.restaurants);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Verdade amigo, você teve um erro ai de lógica, ai tentar passar o valor retornado de restaurantes para sua variável this.restaurants no seu subscriber.

Ai seu output `undefined` é referente ao Watch do javascript de uma variável que não está sendo definida no `loop` do `subscriber`. Está sendo iterado sobre um valor indefinido, resultando assim em algo que não está sendo setado.

Resolvemos o caso usando a arrow function do modo correto

```
this.restaurants = restaurants
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Legal Philip, boa explicação. Me tira uma dúvida se possível. Quando o retorno do subscribe trouxer um objeto complexo para alimentar minha propriedade que também é de um tipo complexo (Objeto) eu preciso realizar a instanciação dela antes de receber o valor? Digo isso pois quando faço a interpolação de uma das propriedades do objeto que declarei e inicio o servidor ele sempre me retorna falando que o objeto é indefinido. Vc saberia o por que disso?

Comment: Talvez vc já tenha conseguido ter feito, mas se puder abrir uma pergunta e mandar o link aqui, eu poderia verificar pra vc @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está adicionando a variável do escopo do componente a ela mesma. Você tem que adicionar a resposta da `API` a variável `restaurants`.

Modifiquei seu método afim de ficar um pouco mais claro.

**Errado ->** `this.restaurants = this.restaurants`

```
export class RestaurantsComponent implements OnInit {

  restaurants: Restaurant[]

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.restaurants()
       .subscribe(resposta => this.restaurants = resposta);
    })
  }
```